# Segmentation fault caused in perl script from regex

Tags: regex, perl

I'm executing a perl script that runs tests in the root directory and subdirectories of the script. For some reason though I'm getting a segmentation fault when the test is in a sub directory. I know it has something to do with the regex code but it's just stipping out everything before the last / and leaving just the file.

```
use strict;
use warnings;


my @files = glob("*.hml");
push(@files, glob("*/*.hml"));

use File::Compare;


$hml = $hml . '/thing.exe ';

my $int = 0;
my @failedTests = qw();
print "Running $hmlfile ... :: ";
    if ($hmlfile =~ s:.*/([^/]+):$1:){

    }

    my $file = substr($newHmlFile, 0, index($newHmlFile , '.'));
    my $log = $file . '.log';
    my $cmd =  $hml . $newHmlFile;



        $cmd = $cmd . ' >  ' . $log . ' 2>&1';

    system ($cmd); 
    my $reflog = 'RefLogs/' . $file . '.log'; 
    if (compare($log, $reflog) == 0) {
            print "$hmlfile PASSED\n";
        unlink $log;
    } else {
        $int++;
        push(@failedTests, "$hmlfile");
        print "$hmlfile *********** FAILED ***********\n";
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that you run this script? It spits me many errors.

Comment: If you see a bunch of lines that say `Global symbol "$hml" requires explicit package name` those are errors caused by you not declaring all of your variables before you use them. If your actual code doesn't have those problems, why did you post broken code?

Comment: @BradGilbert "Why?" Because his original code didn't have `use strict; use warnings;`, but he knew if he didn't add that at the top people would jump all over him for not doing so.  So it got added in to the post. :) (wild guess, probably correct)

Comment: @DavidO I wanted to make sure that it wasn't simply a lack of understanding. Your comment does make more sense than what I was thinking.

Answer (score 0):

A Segmentation Fault in Perl means you found a bug in your version and/or build of Perl.

- Ensure you have the last version available for your operating system.
- Unless you compiled Perl yourself (unlikely), report the bug to the maintainers/vendor of your operating system.

Comment: @ikegami - I was about to write that, but since OP only uses the core module `File::Compare` I decided to not complicate matters.

Comment: I have the most recent version of perl for windows 64bit but still getting a segmentation error.

Comment: @user2785326 - Where did you get perl for windows? That's where you should go with a bugreport. But read [CPAN FAQ How to report a bug in Perl](http://www.cpan.org/misc/cpan-faq.html#How_report_bug_Perl) first. And try to make a *minimal* test-case - how few lines of code can you possibly write and still get the error?